# A sufficient condition for a series of functions to be $\mathcal{C}^i$ (Differentiable)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, partial-derivative

Suppose we have the Fourier Series :

> f(x)=$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k f_k(x)$=$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k \sin(kx)$ defined in $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}$

Using Dirichlet criterion I have shown the sum is continuous in $ [ a, b ]$. Now **I need to show that the sum $ f\in \mathcal{C}^i (a,b) $.**

Is it sufficient to apply Dirichlet criterion (i times) for the sum of the partial derivatives of every $f_k$?

Comment: Are you missing part of the question? It's not in general true that an arbitrary Fourier sine series converges to a continuous function (even assuming it converges in the first place).